# Latencies issues: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

Tags: java, network-programming, connectivity

In my company, I am using a MDM software that is ran with Java and I have got latencies on each click (about 2 to 5 seconds) that I do on the software. Whenever this happens, a pop-up appears and says "Reading / Writing Data" making me thinks that it is getting information from the server at this time.
I do not have access to the Java code directly that is used by the software but I get some logs and one error keeps showing up:

```
WARNING: network problem duing ping()
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:101)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:558)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:454)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:264)
    at com.stibo.util.servicelocator.HttpRMIInvokerApache.ping(HttpRMIInvokerApache.java:646)
    at com.stibo.util.servicelocator.LoadBalancingRMIInvoker.ping(LoadBalancingRMIInvoker.java:312)
    at com.stibo.util.servicelocator.LoadBalancingHttpServiceLocatorImpl.ping(LoadBalancingHttpServiceLocatorImpl.java:188)
    at com.stibo.workbench.component.servicelocator.LoadBalancingHttpServiceLocatorImpl.ping(LoadBalancingHttpServiceLocatorImpl.java:106)
    at com.stibo.workbench.framework.recorder.RecordingServiceLocator.ping(RecordingServiceLocator.java:36)
    at com.stibo.workbench.framework.Main$17.run(Main.java:2663)
```

First of all I tried to go to a place with really fast internet to make sure this was not an issue about my internet connection and it was not.
Then I removed my Antivirus software to see if it was the blocking point but it did not change anything.
Afterwards, I added this software and the OpenJDK used by this software to the authorized list of applications of the firewall, but it did not help.
I even deactivated completely the firewall but it did not change anything too.

The other colleagues do not have the latencies issues.
If you can think of anything that I can check, please let me know. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the firewall is blocking on the server side. You might need to contact server owner and ask them to check any rules on their side blocking your specific IP, or IP range